# QGIS MacOS Installer Version 3.16

Tags: qgis, mac

I tried to download QGIS MacOS Installer Version 3.16 on my Mac Version 11.5.2 (Mac up to date) and after downloading it, it will not allow me to open the software -- I had already agreed to all the terms and conditions. Every time I open it it tells me

> 'QGIS-LTR.app' can't be opened because apple cannot check it for malicious software.This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: it is an Apple OS setting https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

Answer (score 1):

The link below will help, if you still find it hard here are a few easy steps to follow:

1. Go to "System Settings"
2. Click on "Privacy & security"
3. Scroll down to "Security" you will find `'QGIS-LTR' was blocked from  use because it is not from an identified developer.`
4. Clink next to it where it says "Open Anyway"
5. New window will open asking for your password for approval
6. Open QGIS-LTR

https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/install-qgis-ltr.html#install-qgis-on-mac